# Python searching through file with obfuscated characters

Tags: python, steganography

Doing a few challanges, trying to use Python to solve as much as possible (As I know the challange can be completed without the use of Python).
One challange, relating to Steganography, was to find the filename and any extensions within an image. Doing Steg scans with wordlists could resolve this, but somebody mentioned to me that if I opened the image as a word file, then the actual text is visual already.

This is true, but with over 500 lines of this:
�~�b���:ӄ��M��Ɖ��
D�B`�"YOU_GOT_IT_RIGHT!"

I wanted to see if there was a way I could implement a Python script to search through the file and then just show me all English characters (with possibly "!","_","{","}")

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Yes that’s definitely possible, but as StackOverflow isn’t a code-writing service you should try to code it yourself and ask here if you run into problems.

Comment: It seems like they have a little programming experience @barny, Let's not assume they are trying to be sly. I hope I've pointed them in the right direction with my answer. :)

Comment: Not homework at all, it's from a Cyber challange (Hackthebox etc), which I have solved using methods aforementioned (steg), but I was trying to find a way to do so via Python instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to find a solution, with the added feature of being able to pass any file.
Thanks for the advice :)

```
import re
import json
import sys
import argparse

filename = str(sys.argv[1])

with open(filename,"r") as file:
    data = file.read()
    data = ''.join(i for i in data if ord(i)<128)
    print(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

By *"all english characters"*, assuming you mean all ASCII characters; which includes the uppercase and lowercase latin alphabet, numerals, and english special symbols: you could itterate over the file's contents using the python builtin-function [`filter`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/functions.html#filter) and [`string.printables`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/string.html?highlight=ascii#string.printable) like so:

```py
    filtered_contents = ''.join(filter(lambda s: s in string.printables, file_contents))
```

Your question is very vague and it's hard to give you an answer without solving your problem for you. Please reffer to the [community's on topic guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for questions regarding homework help.

> Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've 
>   done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are 
>   having solving it.

If you have a little understanding of Python but are having problems putting your ideas together I'd recommend you explore the [python docs.](https://docs.python.org/3.7/) Whenever I'm having a hard time I find it's very helpful to have on hand. If you want to learn python I'd recommend a google search. There are a bunch of online self-help resources for learning! :)

Comment: Self perscribed homework. Just because it's elective doesn't change it's nature. I create more work for myself all the time like that.

Comment: "Self perscribed homework" I love that. You're right. Thanks for your input, it is greatly appreciated.